# Codeigniter Logs Non Object Error but App Is Working

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter, object

In my codeigniter 3 app logs folder I am seeing the folowing error;

> ERROR - Severity: Notice --> Trying to get property 'title' of
> non-object C:\xampp\htdocs\myapp\application\controllers\Form.php 31

The line in my controller contains;

```
public function view($form_slug) {
    $form_name = str_replace('-', ' ', $form_slug);
    $form_data = $this->Form_model->getFormByName($form_name);
    $data = array(
        'title' => $form_data->title // <-- line 31 generating the error
    );
    $this->load->view('forms/' . $data);
}
```

`var_dump($form_data)` displays;

```
object(stdClass)#22 (3) { ["id"]=> string(1) "3" ["title"]=> string(31) "Some Form Name" ["group"]=> string(1) "1" }
```

My model is;

```
public function getFormByName($form_name)
{
    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from('forms');
    $this->db->where('title', $form_name);
    $query = $this->db->get();
    return $query->row();
}
```

I my view I am displaying the data like;

```
<h1><?php echo $title ?></h1>
```

The strange thing is on the front end everything is working as expected and the data is displaying, but my log folder keeps logging that same error.

Any ideas what the issue is?

Comment: could you please show the complete error message?

Comment: @Vickel the complete error message is in my question already, thanks. `Trying to get property 'title' of non-object`